# Use of sizeof operator in Variadic Template to skip the function for the end of recursion

Tags: c++

I am trying to use operator `sizeof...` to skip the function for the end of recursion by not calling it if there are no argument

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T, typename ...Types>
void Display(T firstArg, Types...Args)
{  
    std::cout << firstArg << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof...(Types) << "\n";
    std::cout << sizeof...(Args) << "\n";
    if (sizeof...(Args) > 0)
    Display(Args...);
}

int main()
{
    Display(1, 2, 3,"hello");
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting following error for `Display(Args...);`

> error C2780: 'void Display(T,Types...)': expects 2 arguments - 0
>   provided

Workaround is to add  function for the end of recursion (which I want to avoid)

```
void Display()
{

}
```

Question is how to avoid end of recursion function

Comment: `if constexpr` ?

Comment: [live demo of @jtbandes suggestion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4786a2a2270c1376)

Comment: @Borgleader Thanks for the solution any small explanation will be helpful ..how did it avoid

Comment: It's not really a workaround to add an end case for recursion. It's how template based recursion is done pre C++17.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can’t do this without some workaround, pre-C++17, unless you rewrite the function to not be recursive. The reason is that the entire function body is substituted, including branches of `if` statements that can never happen. That means that the compiler sees the call to `Display()` with no arguments, even though it would never have happened at runtime.

Since C++17, the solution to this is to use [`if constexpr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) instead of just `if`. That tells the compiler to evaluate the condition at compile time, and not try to compile the branch which doesn’t execute.

Note that “not try to compile” above is a simplification; the link has more details about what exactly is and isn’t done.